# Change data-role on orientationchange in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm building a pretty simple mobile web page with JQM that uses data-role="footer" to create a static footer.

It works well in portrait mode, but when in landscape the footer takes up such a large percentage of the available space that it really affects the user experience.

I tried this:

```
$(window).orientationchange(function(){
    $("#foot").removeAttr("data-role");
});
```

and

```
$(window).orientationchange(function(){
    $("#foot").attr("data-role","none");
});
```

but neither worked.

Does anyone know if there is a way to modify the data role successfully based on a JQM event?

Thanks.